# How to create multiple resources in one main.tf file with Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have created a simple Terraform module to create S3 buckets. It works fine when I want to create only one bucket, but what if I want to create multiple buckets? Surely, I don't need a main.tf file for every bucket I want to create? I realise this is a noob question, but would be grateful for any help.

So instead of doing this (which produces an error anyway), what's the correct approach if all I want to change is the bucket name and tag in the same main.tf file? Can I create a list of bucket names and iterate over them?

```
module "s3_buckets" {
  source       = "../modules/s3_buckets"
  bucket_name = "my-tf-bucket-1"
  tag          = "tf"
}

module "s3_buckets" {
  source       = "../modules/s3_buckets"
  bucket_name = "my-tf-bucket-2"
  tag          = "tf"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [for-each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) meta argument. This could be something like:

```
module "s3_buckets" {
  for_each = toset(["my-tf-bucket-1", "my-tf-bucket-2"])
  source       = "../modules/s3_buckets"
  bucket_name = "${each.key}"
  tag          = "tf"
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you

Comment: This should be enough `bucket_name = each.key`.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that there is an alternative to using `for_each` when you want or need to define different attributes to the resources. The string following `module` can be different:

```
module "s3_bucket1" {
  source       = "../modules/s3_buckets"
  bucket_name = "my-tf-bucket-1"
  tag          = "tf"
}

module "s3_bucket2" {
  source       = "../modules/s3_buckets"
  bucket_name = "my-tf-bucket-2"
  tag          = "tf"
}
```